# App Speed Integration - Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I want to integrate AppSpeed Parameter in my Android Application, for that I have used the following code:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Build and send timing.
t.send(new HitBuilders.TimingBuilder()
    .setCategory(getTimingCategory())
    .setValue(getTimingInterval())
    .setVariable(getTimingName())
    .setLabel(getTimingLabel())
    .build());
```

and called the above sendmethod with appropriate methods, but App Speed section of my portal is still blank. How it will show the data ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
t.sendTiming(loadTime, "resources", "high_scores", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have in mind that the tracks of timing (App speed) sometimes are not refresh immediately like Events and Screenviews in Google Analytics Console. In my case, I had to wait a few hours to see the results. Also check to have in AndroidManifest.xml the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```